# jTable saving each row element in the new line in the .txt file

Tags: java, swing, csv, save, jtable

I have a problem with saving the jTable contents to a file. Every `row` data printed to file makes a new line along. 
So reading from `.txt` looks like this:
[image: Example generated table]

Here is my code:

```
       try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(int i=0; i<jTable2.getRowCount(); i++){
                for(int j=0; j<jTable2.getColumnCount(); j++){
                    bw.write(jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(i, j) + ";");
                }
                bw.newLine();
            } 
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HomeGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}     



  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
             DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable3.getModel();
             Object[] lines = br.lines().toArray();
            /*        */
             for (Object line : lines) {
                   String[] rowData = line.toString().split(";");
                   model.addRow(rowData);
             }
```

What I want is for every `row` to be printed in the same line in the `.txt` but for some reason every time `write` is called, it makes new line in a file.

Comment: try by commenting out bw.newLine();

Comment: In that case, first column contents moves right to the next row `Kalorije`. I have tried many logical solutions, but still can't find the right one... Thanks for the comment!

Comment: If you want all Kalorije values to be printed on the same line, try appending them to a string in the inner for loop, write them before bw.newline(). Also try to flush after every write.

Comment: Considering that the screenshot is absolutely essential to the ability to understand this question, it would be better if you could embed your image directly instead of hosting it on a third part platform that may disappear at any moment in the future.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul Members need certain rep. before they can embed images. I doubt the OP has enough. You could always (suggest) an [edit] though.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table, and factor out the I/O bu doing the conversion to/from a `String`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I didn't know that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

he guys. I can solve your problem:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
     String[] rowData = line[i].toString().split(";");
     model.addRow(rowData);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).